# Usage of `static readonly T[] _emptyArray = new T[0]` as a zero value in C# List<T> implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I was reading the implementation of [List<T>](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) in C#.Net Core when I found something that I don't fully understand. There is a `static readonly T[] _emptyArray = new T[0]` field which is used every time the underlying array (`private T[] _items`) should remain (or be set to) empty. For example in the constructor overload that takes a capacity parameter:

```
 public List(int capacity) {

        /*  Checking if capacity is less then 0  */

        if (capacity == 0)
            _items = _emptyArray;
        else
            _items = new T[capacity];
    }
```

Is this some kind of pattern for memory optimization because I don't see any other reason for this to be used instead of simply setting the underlying array to a new empty array: `_items = new T[0]`.

Comment: Note: the reference source is not the up to date code; the real code is here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs

Comment: I want to know why the implementation is doing `static readonly T[] _emptyArray = new T[0]` rather than `static readonly T[] _emptyArray = Array.Empty<T>()` ... ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson it is commented! https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L30

Comment: Aha! And Marc's update contains the answer: #pragma warning disable CA1825 // avoid the extra generic instantiation for Array.Empty<T>()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> instead of simply setting the underlying array to a new empty array: `_items = new T[0]`.

This would allocate a new empty array lots and lots and lots and lots of times, which is less than ideal. By having a single shared "empty" array, it only does this once per `T` per app-domain. All those empty pointless arrays *can add up*, and have an impact on garbage collection overhead.

You *could* argue "just use `null`", but this would require a lot of extra `null` tests, *and* note that `s_emptyArray` is also used in `ToArray()` as the result for empty lists.